# Как написать assert на один из объектов в массиве json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pytest

Пишу свои первые автотесты с помощью python3 и pytest. Есть некоторые сложности с написанием assert'ов, когда в ответе сервера в формате json есть массив объектов. Конкретно не получается верно указать параметр, по которому я сравниваю. Вот пример ответа:

```
{'users': [{'displayName': 'Тестер Тестеров',
            'familyName': 'Тестеров',
            'givenName': 'Тестер',
            'id': '48',
            'properties': [{'type': 'user_home',
                            'value': '0ce419ba-deb4-4b92-a573-c6809a581236'},
                           {'type': 'name', 'value': 'Tester'},
                           {'type': 'thumbnailUrl',
                            'value': '5223a9c9-b4b6-49cf-88e1-298183d577bf'},
                           {'type': 'displayName', 'value': 'Тестер Тестеров'},
                           {'type': 'birthdate',
                            'value': '1996-04-09T20:00:00.000Z'},
                           {'type': 'thumbnailUrl',
                            'value': '5223a9c9-b4b6-49cf-88e1-298183d577bf'},
                           {'type': 'user_home',
                            'value': '0ce419ba-deb4-4b92-a573-c6809a581236'}],
            'username': 'user_802ff83720d83f9626836f86dd9905e2'},
           {'displayName': 'Anonymous',
            'familyName': None,
            'givenName': 'Anonymous',
            'id': '148',
            'properties': [],
            'username': 'user_60a58d33a3effbcc1bc261e0c69688a1'},
           {'displayName': 'Anonymous',
            'familyName': None,
            'givenName': 'Anonymous',
            'id': '248',
            'properties': [],
            'username': 'user_9fb59ad75b801e0c4671b11db5f66010'}]}
```

И мне надо написать assert на один из объектов в "Properties". Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать? Перепробовал много вариантов. Вот один из примеров,что я пробовал : `assert response_body['users'] == {'id': 148}` . Выдает AssertionError.

Comment: response_body['users'][1]['id'] == '148'

Comment: Это будет не совсем правильное сравнение, как мне кажется. А если у нас запись будет не второй по счету? и не 'id' параметр буду сравнивать?)

Comment: правильное только для вашего примера, конечно; тут только в общих чертах показано, как достучаться до значения словаря в пайтоне

Comment: Немного поясню тогда. Есть еще другой тест-кейс, где выводятся в списке подключенные к приложению провайдеры, их может быть от 0 до 10 например. Ответ мне выдает так же массив объектов, из которого я хочу например выделить конкретный провайдер с конкретным именем, и он может быть как первый в списке, так и пятый. Как тогда в этом случае быть?) Я думал может есть какое то универсальное решение, без указания порядкового номера записи.

Comment: Это не универсальное решение, а магическое - чтобы как-то само находило нужную запись. Магического решения нет. Универсальное решение - найти конкретный элемент с нужным именем (например, обычным проходом по списку циклом), и проверить его id.

Comment: Да нет, тут не магия) Тут надо просто сравнить один из объектов из ответа с тем,что я отправил. Неужели без указания номера записи никак не обойтись? Можно же наверное просто получив список объектов каким-то образом указать что 'name' == 'один из объектов в масииве' без указания порядкового номера записи? То есть к "одному из" указать assert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял ваше условие: код проверяет, что для хотя бы одного объекта из списка `response_body['users']` выполняется условие `user['id'] == '148'`

```
assert any(user['id'] == '148' for user in response_body['users'])
```

Примерно соответствует такому коду:

```
for user in response_body['users']:
    if user['id'] == '148':
        assert True
        break
else:
    assert False
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлексейКуклин если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым (поставить галку слева от ответа)